# How to get larger day in list?

Tags: c#

I have 1 List <> contain many day/month/year in C#. I want to get the biggest day(base on month/year to compare) in the list. How to do it's?

Like:

```
2/5/2015 6/5/2015 16/8/2015 30/7/2015 //note that is from each time in DTOSaveFromFile
```

The biggest day is: `16/8/2015`

Here my code:

```
List<DTOSaveFromFile> lst = Load();

public static List<DTOSaveFromFile> Load()
{
   string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(dataPath);
   return (from i in data select new DTOSaveFromFile(i)).ToList<DTOSaveFromFile>();
}

foreach (var rows in lst)
{
}    

public class DTOSaveFromFile : List<string>
{
    public string reportName { get; set; }
    public string eMail { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }

    public DTOSaveFromFile(string _reportname, string _email, string _time)
    {
        reportName = _reportname;
        eMail = _email;
        time = _time;
    }
}
```

Comment: So ````_time```` is a string like ````01/07/2016```` ?

Comment: `_time` like this: `07-01-2016`

Comment: @fds see my answer, i think it can prove how to do what you want. But look it is didatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final Solution**

You can do it with LINQ in one line:

```
DateTime biggest = lst
    .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.time, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) //to get the list of `string` of `time` from your List<DTOSaveFromFile> + //To convert it to DateTime 
    .Max(); //Get the max among the DateTime
```

---

**Explanation**

(*added as it is required by the asker for more clarification.*)

This is what you actually do:

1. Get `IEnumerable<DateTime>` from `List<DTOSaveFromFile>`
2. For each `DTOSaveFromFile`, get its `DTOSaveFromFile.time` which is a `string` (note the `x.time`),
3. You get the `DateTime` value for each `x.time` `string` by using `DateTime.ParseExact` with **right** `format` (in this case being `d/M/yyyy`).
4. Once all the `DateTime`has been put into a single IEnumerable, find the maximum among them by using `Max()`.

---

**Step-by-step guidance**

1. Basically if you do `Select(x => x.time)` on a `List<DTO>` where `DTO` class contains `time` field which is a `string` (like your case), then instead of having a List of DTO you have an "List" (or more properly called IEnumerable) of `string`, which is the type of your `time` field. Thus

   ```
   List<string> timeList = lst.Select(x => x.time).ToList();
   ```

   will give you `List<string> timeList` which contains only `time` (`string`).

2-3. Then next, for each of the `string` in the `timeList`, you need to process to `DateTime` to find the maximum among them. And how do you do this? By using `DateTime.ParseExact` for each `string` with the correct `format` argument for the `DateTime.ParseExact`, which is `"d/M/yyyy"`

Thus, you may be tempted to do something like this

```
List<DateTime> dtlist = new List<DateTime>();
foreach (string time in timeList){
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(x.time, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    dtlist.Add(dt);
}
```

Which will give you `List<DateTime>` called `dtlist`

But in `Linq`, you could do this **without** `foreach` loop!

```
Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

4. Then finally, given `dtlist`, you want to find the maximum. You only need to use `Max` to get it.

   ```
   DateTime biggest = dtlist.Max();
   ```

---

**Brute Force to LINQ**

Now the actual solution is combining all those steps in **one** `LINQ` line.

So what you do here:

```
List<string> timeList = lst.Select(x => x.time).ToList(); //Step 1

List<DateTime> dtlist = new List<DateTime>(); //Step 2-3
foreach (string time in timeList){
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(x.time, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    dtlist.Add(dt);
}

DateTime biggest = dtlist.Max(); //Step 4
```

Is equal to one line `LINQ`

```
DateTime biggest = lst
    .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.time, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) //to get the list of `string` of `time` from your List<DTOSaveFromFile> + //To convert it to DateTime 
    .Max(); //Get the max among the DateTime
```

---

**Final Solution (again)**

Given your `List<DTOSaveFromFile>`

For the sake of explanation, using **two** `selects` in `LINQ` you could do it in one line like this:

```
DateTime biggest = lst.Select(x => x.time) //to get the list of `string` of `time` from your List<DTOSaveFromFile>
    .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) //To convert it to DateTime
    .Max(); //Get the max among the DateTime
```

Your value is in the `biggest` variable.

Note that now you can further simplify the answer by using one `select`:

```
DateTime biggest = lst
    .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.time, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) //to get the list of `string` of `time` from your List<DTOSaveFromFile> + //To convert it to DateTime 
    .Max(); //Get the max among the DateTime
```

Comment: Yup, I want DTOSaveFromFile like a List<>. I was removed this line because it's not necessary.

Comment: @fds I expanded my explanation. Kindly take a look.

Comment: Thanks @lan you awesome. I know yours explain. But I don't know how to convert `x.time` to DateTime. Like: `Select(x => x.time).ToString("d/M/yyyy)` but it still is `string`. I must convert it before using Linq to select and chosen a `Max()` values in `biggest`?

Comment: @fds "But I don't know how to convert `x.time` to `DateTime`. Like: `Select(x => x.time).ToString("d/M/yyyy)` but it still is `string`" -> You need to use `DateTime.ParseExact`. I give 1, 2-3, and 4 numbers to my explanation. See it it helps.

Comment: Thanks @lan. I will create new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Max` method of linq, so just try this:

```
var dateBase = new DateTime(2016,01,01);
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(i=> dateBase.AddDays(i).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).ToList();
dates.ForEach(d=>Console.WriteLine(d));
Console.WriteLine();
var bigger = dates.Max(d=>DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine("Bigger Day: {0}",bigger.Day);
Console.WriteLine("Bigger Month: {0}",bigger.Month);
Console.WriteLine("Bigger Year: {0}",bigger.Year);
```

See it working in my fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gxw4Pm

Comment: You're missing the parsing - the OP's `time` field is a string.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie my answer is from before he edits the question X)

Answer (score 1):

You can populate the dates in a list and then use order by as shown below.

```
private DateTime GetLargeDate(List<DateTime> dates)
    {
        dates = dates.OrderByDescending(t => t.Date).ToList();
        return dates[0];
    }
```